# Menu component with react router not rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, navbar

i'm just new to react router, this is my first try :)

***Problem***

If i click on the proper link ( `<NavLink to='/BubbleSort'>Bubble sort</NavLink>` e.g.)  the i don't get the content, the page still continue to be without content.

***Code***

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import {
  Route,
  HashRouter
} from 'react-router-dom';
import BubbleSort from './Components/BubbleSort';
import InsertionSort from './Components/InsertionSort';
import Menu from './Components/Menu';


class App extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
    <HashRouter>
      <div className="App">
        <Menu/>
        <div className="content">
          <Route path="./Components/BubbleSort" component = { BubbleSort }/>
          <Route path="./Components/InsertionSort" component = { InsertionSort }/>
        </div>
      </div>
    </HashRouter>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Down below we have the `Menu` component

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import './Menu.css';
import {
    NavLink,
  } from 'react-router-dom';



class Menu extends Component {

    render() {
        return(
                <nav className="navbar">
                    <div 
                        className="nav-button" >
                        <NavLink to='/BubbleSort'>Bubble sort</NavLink>
                    </div>
                    <div 
                        className="nav-button">
                        <NavLink to="./InserionSort">Insertion sort</NavLink>
                    </div>
                    <div 
                        className="nav-button" >
                        <NavLink>Selection sort</NavLink>
                    </div>
                    <div 
                        className="nav-button" 
                        a href="/mergeSort">
                        Merge sort
                    </div>
                    <div 
                        className="nav-button" 
                        a href="/quickSort">
                        Quick sort
                    </div>
                    <div 
                        className="nav-button" 
                        a href="/radixSort">
                        Radix sort
                    </div>
                </nav>
        )
    }
}

export default Menu;
```

***Expected Behaviour***

if I click on `<NavLink to='/BubbleSort'>Bubble sort</NavLink>`the page has to shows the actual content of the `BubbleSort` component.

***Consideration***

1) The `Menu` component in the folder "./Components/Menu", the App.js is in the main Src folder, the BubbleSort.js is in the folder "./Components/BubbleSort"

i followed [this link](https://www.kirupa.com/react/creating_single_page_app_react_using_react_router.htm) to made this little navbar, i think that the problem is something related to the use of the Menu component, but i don't know how to fix it.

Comment: try add ´<Switch></Switch>´  inside <Menu> and out of <div class="content">

Comment: `Route` and `NavLink`  should have `relative path`

Comment: @JorgeFélixCazarez The problem here is because of improper syntax and component usage. `Switch` is a totally different story. :)

Comment: @Legeo is using different `path` and `to` in `Route` and `NavLink` components respectively. That' s why the `NavLink` are not working

Comment: I didn't see the <NavLink>, its true @AjayGupta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Route path should not be the component file path.
it should be what you put inside (to) props inside NavLink.
[Demo Reference code pen](https://codepen.io/carloluis/pen/gWzPzd)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import {
  Route,
  HashRouter
} from 'react-router-dom';
import BubbleSort from './Components/BubbleSort';
import InsertionSort from './Components/InsertionSort';
import Menu from './Components/Menu';


class App extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
    <HashRouter>
      <div className="App">
        <Menu/>
        <div className="content">
          <Route path="/BubbleSort" component = { BubbleSort }/>
          <Route path="/InsertionSort" component = { InsertionSort }/>
        </div>
      </div>
    </HashRouter>
    );
  }
}

export default App;

import React, {Component} from 'react';
import './Menu.css';
import {
    NavLink,
  } from 'react-router-dom';



class Menu extends Component {

    render() {
        return(
                <nav className="navbar">
                    <div 
                        className="nav-button" >
                        <NavLink to='/BubbleSort'>Bubble sort</NavLink>
                    </div>
                    <div 
                        className="nav-button">
                        <NavLink to="/InserionSort">Insertion sort</NavLink>
                    </div>
                    <div 
                        className="nav-button" >
                        <NavLink>Selection sort</NavLink>
                    </div>
                    <div 
                        className="nav-button" 
                        a href="/mergeSort">
                        Merge sort
                    </div>
                    <div 
                        className="nav-button" 
                        a href="/quickSort">
                        Quick sort
                    </div>
                    <div 
                        className="nav-button" 
                        a href="/radixSort">
                        Radix sort
                    </div>
                </nav>
        )
    }
}

export default Menu;
```

Comment: thank you for your contribution. Please make sure when you answer a question, you also explain what was the problem with the OP's code. It helps to better understand the problem and the solution. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2):

`Route` and `NavLink` Component should be written like this:-

```
<Route path='/Components/BubbleSort' component={ BubbleSort } />
<Route path='/Components/InsertionSort' component={ InsertionSort } />
```

`NavLink` component will be written like the following:-

```
<NavLink to='/Components/InsertionSort'>Insertion Sort</NavLink>
```